# I Want Some Ice Cream

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, english, word-property

<sub>This is similar to the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles. Giving credit where credit is due.</sub>

---

I was sitting at Landra Hort's Mystery Ice Cream Shoppe slurping on the last of my Birou Sundae when I noticed a man walk up to the counter and ask the cashier for a free scoop. The cashier said, "Give me a word with no two." The man said to her:

> word

The cashier smiled and said, "Excellent! What flavor would you like?"

The man asked for the smooth Mean Chart Hug Nag, and received one scoop for free.

Mystified, I watched as someone else walked in and asked for a free scoop. The cashier asked the same question: "Give me a word with no two." The customer said:

> lemonade

and received his scoop of the spicy Devious ice cream. Determined to find the pattern, I sat and watched day after day, making a note of what words had "no two." Here is a small sample:

> laptop, mathematics, mist, overflow, green, three, four, score, cream.

And a few words that didn't make it:

> puzzling, stack, exchange, (*someone had ideas, I guess ;D*) red, one, two, upvote.

One poor fellow was denied after giving the word

> flower

He clarified that he meant *flour* rather than *flower* and received his scoop of Grape Nut Leper Lin.

For what it's worth, some of the other flavors that I heard ordered were Mix-o Hone and H. M. Moe.

Confident of my success, I went up to the counter after a week of observation and asked for a free scoop of ice cream. The cashier, as usual, said, "Give me a word with no two." I responded with

> ice

and happily enjoyed my free scoop of Ring Herder ice cream.

## What other words could get you some ice cream?

Comment: I used a computer to check which do and do not have a two in them, so hopefully this one won't have any mistakes in it @Deusovi

Comment: He should have given you a scoop of [BnJ](https://www.benjerry.com/) "Radon" ice cream instead.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan He could have, but that would have been cruel to would-be solvers. At any rate, I prefer the Jon Brand (although Radon is a _very_ close second). By the way, should you ever visit Landra's place, the "ug" in Mean Chart H _ug_ Nag is not pronounced.

Comment: Other words: I will give you 20 dollars :)

Comment: * Answering to your question "What other words could get you some ice cream?"

Comment: Incidentally, who does ring herder describe??

Comment: @El-Guest Oh, I think you can figure that out. But if you'd like a [little hint](https://anagram-solver.net/RINGHERDER), there you go. Don't judge me ;P

Comment: @Brandon_J awful, that’s actually awful of you. (+1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some other words that should get you free ice cream:

> I 
>  need
>  the 
>  frozen 
>  goods 
>  now

But why?
The answer lies within

> Summing the letters in the word (where A=1,Z=26) and then converting the sum to binary.
> If the number has a 1 in the second digit place, then that means it has a two.

Words with no two:

> ```
> ice:   9  +  3 + 5          = 17 = 010001
> the:   20 +  8 + 5          = 33 = 100001
> cream: 3  + 18 + 5 + 1 + 13 = 40 = 101000
> ```

Words with a two:

> ```
> two:   20 + 23 + 15         = 58 = 111010
> red:   18 +  5 + 4          = 27 = 011011
> stack: 19 + 20 + 1 + 3 + 11 = 54 = 110110
> ```

Now the only question I have is what kind of training the cashiers go through to figure these out.

Comment: This is correct! Checkmark will come soon.

Answer (score 2):

I’m thinking this is wrong, because there are some words that break the pattern, but could it be that

> When you translate each word using A1Z26 and then add all of the numbers together, a word that gets you ice cream is even (as in flour) and a word that doesn’t is odd (as in flower)?

So a word that could get you ice cream is

> GUEST?

I have no idea if this has anything to do with anything, but

> All of the ice cream flavours are anagrams of prominent PSE users: 
>  Landra Hort: Rand al’ Thor 
>  Birou: Rubio 
>  Mean Chart Hug Nag: Gareth McCaughan 
>  Devious: Deusovi 
>  Grape Nut Leper Lin: GentlePurpleRain 
>  Mix-o Hone: Hexomino 
>  H. M. Moe: M Oehm 
>  Ring Herder: ***Red Herring***

So could I have a scoop of

> Lug’s Tee ice cream??

Comment: Looks to me like this gives the wrong result for "lemonade", "mist", "green", "stack", "one", "two", and "ice".

Comment: Your answer is similar in style to the final answer, so props! Incidentally, "guest" is a word with no two (as is "el"), but it appears that you got that ice cream by luck.

Comment: Also, the condition seems almost _backwards_ relative to the name it's been given.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan correct; this rule is not the answer.

Comment: @Brandon_J "A1Z26" is the usual term, I think.

Comment: I figured as much, especially given the name, but I was struggling to find other differences...